# Share translations between multiple locales in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I have locales that come in the form of en-GB, en-US, de-DE, de-AT, de-CH etc..

Now the issue is that de-DE, de-AT, de-CH all share the same translations. 
So having to define them multiple times is annoying and not very DRY.

Before anyone suggests just using :de as locale, I can't. That's how I did it before and due to some business logic I can't change the new en-GB format was forced onto me.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about cleaning up your yml-files?

Comment: at the moment I only have a de.yml and all three locales (de-DE, de-AT.. ) should be using that one for localization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using YAML for you localization then you already have necessary tools. YAML allows you to write something like mixins:

```
en: &english
   hello: Hello, %{username}!

en-GB:
  <<: *english

en-US:
  <<: *english
```

I hope you got the idea of DRYing here.

Comment: Awesome.. I tried that already but I made the mistake of naming the label &en so I got psych parser errors once I started up rails.. 
With another label this works..

Answer (score 1):

Still DRY still but more importantly your translations aren't duplicated in memory :

Create an i18n initializer that includes fallbacks :

```
require "i18n/backend/fallbacks" 
I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Fallbacks)
```

And move your translations into `de:` and `en:` locales.

A call like this

```
I18n.t :foo, :locale => 'de-AT'
```

will first look for `de-AT.foo` and providing there is no match, will look for `de.foo`.

More info on the [i18n wiki](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/wiki/Fallbacks).